# Who manufactured these windows and doors?

Tags: doors, windows

I am trying to find a replacement threshold for my back door, but I haven't a clue who the manufacturer is. There is a logo etched in the lower right corner of the glass; however, I cannot figure out who's logo it is. They're hard to photograph, but I finally got a decent image of the etch. If anybody can point me at the manufacturer, that would be greatly appreciated!

[image: logo etched in lower right corner of window]

Comment: Somewhere on the upper East Coast. https://agma.glass/ "The Architectural Glass & Metal Association (AGMA) is a community of glazing contractors & affiliated service providers in southeastern Pennsylvania, southern New Jersey, the State of Delaware, and the Eastern Shore of Maryland."

Comment: Good catch. I'm in Western Canada, so pretty far from that region. Just went through the list of affiliates without spotting that logo. The "A" in AGMA, if that is what it says, is slanted without a line in the middle, sort of like an italicized capital lambda. None of the agma logos online seem to have this style.

Answer (score 3):

That logo will be the manufacturer of the insulated glazing unit (just the glass).

Door companies will use IGUs + Doors and pieces from various manufacturers to create a door that is then sold to the consumer.  In my experience the door manufacturers put their mark on the top edge of the door or via a metal plate on one of the width edges.

Comment: So I have looked all over the door, including the top, behind hinges, etc. and this is the only logo I see. Same logo on my front door and every window in the house. Even if they don't make the rest of the door, I'd still like to know who they are.

Comment: What if you look down at the separator between the glass panes sometimes this will be marked with the name of the company that assembled the glass and the year?

Comment: I did look there before asking here but will check again in the morning. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: No such luck. I contacted the builder, hopefully I'll get an answer from them tomorrow.